# How to import Swift module once and use everywhere in the whole project

Tags: xcode, swift

In Objective-C project, we can import header files in `.pch` file so that we don't need to import elsewhere. But how can I achieve this in a Swift project?

Comment: Also related: [Is there a Prefix Header (or something with this functionality) in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28703739/3804019)