# Import a framework on a file to use on all other files in swift

Tags: swift, import, pch

I've started coding in Swift with a game project using SpirteKit

I want to import SpriteKit in a file like a .pch file, so all the other files in the project can use and no need to call

```
import SKSpriteKit
```

again. But Swift seems not support .pch file

Is there any alternative way to achieve it

Comment: Found my dupe: [Is there a Prefix Header (or something with this functionality) in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694537/is-there-a-prefix-header-or-something-with-this-functionality-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

I know I've answered this before, but digging out duplicates is cumbersome on mobile, so I'll just answer it again for now...

Unlike with (Obj)C (specifically, C before modules were introduced in Xcode 4), there is no cost to having the same `import` statement at the top of multiple files in a project. If there were a way to say "import SpriteKit for all files in my project", it wouldn't save on compilation time the way a pch file can for C.

On the other hand, even though you're typing the same `import` statement in each file, there's a benefit to that in terms of clarity. It lets you choose *not* to import the same modules in every file (which can be important for optimization and controlling which overloaded/generic functions get used), and it makes clear to readers of your code what its dependencies are. (Because it sucks to copy/paste code from some file and not know what modules you need to make it compile again in its new location.)

Comment: Yes, you're right about the attention and clarification. But in the large project, for example about UIKit and UIFoundation, every files and classes need them, I think it's really terrible if I have to type them on each file or even copy paste. Again in a big project, not just only these framework are imported, I suppose Apple did a horrible thing when they remove the use of pch file. Anyway, thank @rickster