# How do I import the new logging functions in iOS 10 / Sierra / Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode, logging

There is a [new logging system](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) in iOS 10 and macOS Sierra.

But I can't seem to make it work in Xcode. `os_log` is not recognized, and neither is any other function / constant mentioned in the docs.

> Use of unresolved identifier 'os_log'

Do I need to link a framework or import a header or something? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: In Swift, `import os.log`. In Objective-C, `@import os.log;`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In Swift:

```
import os

os_log("Some message")
```

In Objective-C:

```
#import <os/log.h>

os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Some message");
```

Comment: To those of you are annoyed by the requirement of adding a `import os.log` to any Swift file which you might ever want to drop a `os_log(...)` into, [here is some consolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694537/is-there-a-prefix-header-or-something-with-this-functionality-in-swift)

Comment: To log with parameters you can use: `os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Authorization Response: %@", URL);`

Answer (score 1):

There are also bit advanced/organized way of logging, as mentioned at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code

In Swift,

```
let defaultLog = Logger()
defaultLog.log("This is a default message.")
            
// Log a message to the default log and debug log level
defaultLog.debug("This is a debug message.")

// Log an error to a custom log object.
let customLog = Logger(subsystem: "com.your_company.your_subsystem", 
          category: "your_category_name")
customLog.error("An error occurred!")
```

In Objective C

```
// Log a message to the default log and debug log level
os_log_with_type(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, OS_LOG_TYPE_DEBUG, "This is a debug message.");
    
// Log an error to a custom log object.
os_log_t customLog = os_log_create("com.your_company.your_subsystem", "your_category_name");
os_log_with_type(customLog, OS_LOG_TYPE_ERROR, "An error occurred!");
```