# Why is my ios/osx framework ignoring GCC_PREFIX_HEADER?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

## TLDR Question

Why are my changes to `Prefix Header` being ignored? How do I get my xcode project to acknowledge the `Prefix Header` a.k.a `GCC_PREFIX_HEADER`.

## Context

I am trying to add a pch file to my framework for ios/osx. I have been following the instructions I've found in other S.O. posts([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26126037/464770)), but haven't even been able even get the `GCC_PREFIX_HEADER`/`Prefix Header` field to give me a compilation error when I type an invalid address.

## Steps

[image]
1. Select `NetworkFramework.xcodeproj` in XCode 8.3.2

2. - For each of:

     - my project, called `NetworkFramework`;
     - my targets, called `NetworkFrameWorkMobile` and `NetworkFrameworkMac`
   - Set:

     - `Build Settings > Apple LLVM 8.1 - Language > Precompile Prefix Header`

       - To: `YES`
     - `Build Settings > Apple LLVM 8.1 - Language > Prefix Header`

       - To: `GIBBERISH` (I think this should be invalid input)
3. Clean the build directory:

   - <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>
4. Build

   - <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

## What I expect

Since I named the prefix header `GIBBERISH` I expect there to be some sort of build error

## What I get

A successful build, with no errors

## Other things I have tried

- Closing and reopening XCode
- Deleting `/Users/topguncoder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` + restarting xcode + clean build

## Reason for wanting a prefix header

I'm trying to get `CocoaLumberJack` for this project.
They recommend having the following in the pch file:

```
#define LOG_LEVEL_DEF ddLogLevel
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a prefix header in Swift.
But if you want you still can, using Objective-C Bridging Header.
Read both answers at this thread:

[Is there a Prefix Header (or something with this functionality) in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694537/is-there-a-prefix-header-or-something-with-this-functionality-in-swift)